# Numpy argmax on multiple axes determined by other vectors

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, argmax

Say I have a 3d matrix called A with shape (100,4,100). And also two vectors of 200 values each, created like this:

```
b = np.random.randint(0, 3, 200)
c = np.random.randint(0, 99, 200)
```

How can I efficiently find the argmax for each of A[b,c,:]?

I am able to do a for loop, which would look like this:

```
for i in range(200):
    np.argmax(A[b[i], c[i], :])
```

Do I have any more efficient options by avoiding the for loop?

Comment: `A[b,c].argmax(1)`?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed! Want to create an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: Would encourage you to post your own answer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as suggested by Divakar above is to use [ndarray.argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argmax.html#numpy.ndarray.argmax), so it would look like `A[b,c].argmax(1)`